# vertical slider need to be more customized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this vertical slider, which works as it should, but I need to change some values dynamically.
https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/slider-vertical.html

The values I need to change are "min", "max" and "value" in this function:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

The values "min" , "max" and "value" must be set at each page reload, i.e before the user slide the slider up or down. They are generated within PHP codes before the page is shown. They are saved in variables such as $_min; $_max; and $_value;
Now the question is how do I send them to the javascript function and how do I catch them. 
In a simple function like the following I put them in the parentesis...

```
<input type="text" onClick="myVal(<?php echo $_min ?>);">
```

And then catch them via function name like this:

```
function myVal(a)
{alert(a) ; 
----- do something more ---
}
```

But now I dont even know the name of the function. Its not javascript, it's jquery

I hope now I am clearer :)

Comment: I am just wondering why is this question has got (-2) . This is actually my best formatted Q so far. I put a great deal of effort into it! I am sorry that my native language is not english. But that is something I can not do anything about it. The people that gave it negatives, would you please explain why, so I could learn from it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP/HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="slider-vertical" 
     data-slider-min="<?php echo $_min ?>"
     data-slider-max="<?php echo $_max ?>"
     data-slider-value="<?php echo $_value ?>"
>
</div>
```

Your Javascript should look like this:

```
$(document).ready( function()  {

    var $slider = $("#slider-vertical"),
        min = $slider.data("slider-min"),
        max = $slider.data("slider-max"),
        value = $slider.data("slider-value");

    $slider.slider({

        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: min,
        max: max,
        value: value,
        slide: function( event, ui ) { $("#amount").val( ui.value ); }

    });

});
```

Explanation:

We use PHP to append the variables as `html data attributes` to a HTML element. We then can access this  data with jQuery, and set the values on the slider.

PHP renders the page the page on the server with the data, and then when a user loads it, their browser will tell jQuery to collect the information and create a slider from it.

the jQuery is wrapped in a function which makes sure the Document is ready to be manipulated.

No need for a user to interact with a click/anything :)

Answer (score 2):

jquery-UI slider has APIs for that. Check [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-min).

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "max", 50 );
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "min", 10);
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );
```

Comment: How do I use this? I can't call the function in the HTML code. I have only this <div id="slider-vertical" style="height:200px;"></div>

Comment: You could learn the language Javascript, there are various sites. But to answer your comment, use <script> javascript code </script> to run a script in HTML

Answer (score 2):

You should check the documentation before you ask a question,

```
$( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "option", "max", 300 );
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

To execute the code within php you can echo the statement as such:

```
<?php
    echo "<script> $( '#slider-vertical' ).slider( 'option', 'max', " + $_max + "); </script>";
?>
```

Comment: It's not helping you know. How do I put them in work? Where are they being set? I want to set them at page upload.

Comment: Your question is not helping, if you want a better answer please update your question and explain the complete situation.

Comment: I have now explained the situation a bit more. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this

```
min: - document.getElementById("diff").value,
max: document.getElementById("diff").value,
value: 0,
document.getElementById("bild").style.top = ( ui.value );
document.getElementById("klip22").style.top = ( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" )
```

Its working now!
Thanks